# asp.net core xproj file has import that doesn't exist on Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created an ASP.NET core application with Visual Studio and the .NET core tools.  It runs fine on Windows, but when I copy it to Ubuntu for deployment and then run it, I get:

```
....xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.0-preview4-004233/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v14.0/DotNet/Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found.
```

Which makes sense, because Visual Studio isn't installed on Ubuntu.  Why is it there?  I tried removing the import from the xproj and that causes other problems:

```
error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project.
```

Here's the xproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>ca453b3a-1bb5-4ed8-bbe5-fe1e627a9f76</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>abc</RootNamespace>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath Condition="'$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)'=='' ">.\obj</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)'=='' ">.\bin\</OutputPath>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet.Web\Microsoft.DotNet.Web.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
</Project>
```

I'm new to ASP.NET core, and currently lost in a sea of versions, tools, previews... I think the VS tools targets 1.0.0, but when I installed dotnet core on linux I got 1.1.0, so I also installed 1.0.0 and use

```
dotnet run --framework 1.0.0
```

What am I supposed to be doing to create a web project in VS (2015) and deploy it to linux?

**UPDATE** from further googling I found (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5420) that I should install ".NET Core Tooling Preview 1 for Visual Studio 2015", but I can't do that because I'm on linux, so what should I do?

Is it not possible to develop a web app in VS and deploy to linux?

**UPDATE 2**
Ok, so despite everything I'm reading saying that you run a web app with dotnet run, I found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3235) that I should use dotnet myDLL.dll (and that works, on Windows at least I haven't tried on Linux yet)

So what's the reason?  Core versions?

dotnet run is much better than having to know the correct DLL name, so I'm guessing dotnet run is for v1.1?  Have I somehow built my project for v1.0?

I am lost with all the versioning and previews etc etc, I'd appreciate a explanation.  I thought I was downloading the latest stuff, and I thought the VS toolkit was version agnostic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the correct way to do it (for SDK 1.0.0) is

1. Publish from VS
2. Copy content of publish output folder to Linux
3. Run it with `dotnet myapp.dll` (instead of dotnet run).

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused about the .xproj file on your Linux machine. If you publish your web app locally you should not see an .xproj file in between the published files. Because .xproj is only a file Visual Studio needs. Dotnet core only needs a project.json file and a void static main to function.

1) Try the guide in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction

2) Or follow the guidelines from Scott Hanselman's post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNETCoreWebsiteToACheapLinuxVMHost.aspx

Comment: Thanks but `dotnet publish`, and then `dotnet run` inside the publish folder just gives `error DOTNET1017: Project file does not exist 'C:\path\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish\project.json'.`

Comment: And if I copy the project.json from the project folder, and try to run, it says The application to execute does not exist: 'C:\path\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish.dll'  the path is wrong anyway, but even so there is no dll called publish.dll